# The React App works during `npm start` but returns 404 after build

Tags: reactjs, npm, server, yarnpkg

I'm developing a React App and everything works fine during `npm start`. After I do `npm run build` and run `serve -s build` under the build folder, the terminal told me it's serving but when I checked out `http://localhost:5000/`, it was

> 404 The requested path could not be found

Then I installed live-server and run `live-server` under the build folder, the App worked fine again. But I don't understand why `serve -s build` was not working properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: does it work if you run the `serve -s` from inside the build folder ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Yes it works! Thanks! I don't understand why the terminal told me to run `serve -s build`.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli can you put that as an answer then xfx can accept your answer. serve -s also worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This doesn't work because you're running the command from inside the build folder already.

If you run **serve --help** you can see the usage documentation for this command.  The **serve** command accepts an input of **folder_name** for the files it should serve.  If no folder is specified it will serve the folder that you are running the command in (which is why Gabriele's response above solved your problem).  You could run the **serve -s build** command from the parent folder that contains the *build* folder and it would also work.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe when you run your application, the port of your application is open, check if you are listening:

Find

```
[sudo] lsof -i: 3000
```

Kill

```
kill -9 <PID>
```